# Problem with Caesar cipher in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, caesar-cipher

I have the following instructions as part of a Caesar cipher program.

```
overFlow:
    sub bl, 1Ah
    ret

underFlow:
    add bl, 1Ah
    ret

correctFlow:
    cmp bl, 7Ah
    jg overFlow
    cmp bl, 61h
    jl underFlow
    ret

enc_byte:
    add bl, encOffset
    call correctFlow
    ret
```

An ASCII lowercase letter is put into `BL` and after *enc_byte* is called, it shifts the letter by *encOffset* letters and corrects for an overflow.

But for some reason the compare in *correctFlow* doesn't work correctly. When `BL=8Dh` in *correctFlow*, the `jg overFlow` instruction does not jump, and instead `jl underFlow` jumps after the second `cmp`. Why is this happening? 8Dh is clearly greater than 7Ah, so why doesn't it jump as expected?

I know the returns are weird. The *overFlow* and *underFlow* labels are the ones that return the call to *correctFlow*. This is intentional and as far as I know, doesn't have anything to do with the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `jg` and `jl` treat the outcome of `cmp` as if the two operands were **signed** numbers.

`7Ah` and `8Dh` represent signed numbers +122 and -115, respectively. Obviously, the latter is the smallest.

What you need is **unsigned** comparison. Use instructions `ja` and `jb` instead.